# AES decryption not working properly

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm currently working on some encryption things and I was using raw RSA before, which I discontinued due to the lack of having more data encrypted with low key sizes (only 501 bytes with 4096 bit keysize).
Now I try to use the common AES/RSA combination (encrypting an AES session key with RSA and then encrypting data with this AES key)

My problem is as follows:
When a client connects to a server, the server first sends its RSA Public Key with 4096 bits keysize. After that, the client generates a session key for this session and encrypts it with the Public Key of the server. Then the client sends the encrypted session key to the server, where it's decrypted again and a Cipher is initialized.

To solve the main conflict, I send the AES key NOT ENCRYPTED at the moment, but it doesn't work either. When the server receives something from the client, the output is something like this:

```
Got some line from client: ÖÞà^ò}íŽ€;ÕrJ]ám+›míé?1©ûPü.ÃæV.ë-½f?•Ž[öº[ÿÂÌwvñ{$Ä+ÞQ0IÄØþ3<ú«¸bræ‰ÚÔ¶Â¼ÔI—tîí‚øT%+ÑÓä™)
Got some line from client: O¬Aé0ü? ¿
Got some line from client: f±OßStæÂd{,¨3ýk¿ËEfo„|a>«ž6ÀN`˜ržöžuØÀ²©ïZq‹¡êœþpE¥
```

As you can see, it's obviously not what it should be (commands for the server). Here's some code for you:

LoginHandler.java (Server)

```
try
{
    // Transfer of the RSA 4096 key to encrypt session key
    X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Storage.getKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded());
    String keyBuffer = HexEncoder.byteArrayToHexString(x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    this.targetUser.getOutputStream().write(keyBuffer + "\n");
    this.targetUser.getOutputStream().flush();
    System.out.println("After key write");
    System.out.println("pubkey buffer: " + HexEncoder.hexStringToByteArray(keyBuffer).hashCode());
    System.out.println("string key: " + keyBuffer);

    this.targetUser.initDecryption();

    String loginDecrypted = this.targetUser.getEncryptionTool().decrypt(this.targetUser.getInputStream().readLine());
    if (loginDecrypted.startsWith("LOGIN"))
    {   
        if (this.doLoginProcedure(loginDecrypted)) // <- The main login stuff happens here
        {   
            try
            {
                // Old key transfer 
                /**byte[] clientPubkeyBuffer = HexEncoder.hexStringToByteArray(this.targetUser.getInputStream().readLine());

                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(clientPubkeyBuffer);
                PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);**/

                // Receive the encrypted session key from client
                byte[] wrappedKey = new byte[16];
                this.targetUser.getRawInput().read(wrappedKey, 0, 16);

                System.out.println("key wrapped: " + HexEncoder.byteArrayToHexString(wrappedKey));

                // Decrypt the session key
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Storage.getKeyPair().getPrivate());
                SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(wrappedKey, "AES");

                if (!IMServer.getServer().getCache().isKeyCached((SecretKey)key))
                {
                    IMServer.getServer().getCache().addKey(this.targetUser.getUserID(), (SecretKey)key);
                }

                // Old encryption initialization
                /**this.targetUser.initEncryption(publicKey);**/

                // New encryption
                this.targetUser.setEncryptionStreams(Encryption.decryptInputStream(this.targetUser.getRawInput(), (SecretKey)key), Encryption.encryptOutputStream(this.targetUser.getRawOutput(), (SecretKey)key));

                IMServer.getServer().getClientHandlerByUser(targetUser.getUserID()).start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.targetUser.logout();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            targetUser.logout();
            targetUser = null;
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    IMServer.getServer().getSystemLogger().log(Logger.ERROR, "Failure during login procedure");
}
```

The method "setEncryptionStreams()" (Server):

```
public void setEncryptionStreams(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    this.input = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    this.output = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

    this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

    System.out.println("Finished setting new streams.");
}
```

The method "initEncryption()" (Client):

```
public void initEncryption()
{
    try
    {
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        keygen.init(random);
        SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, CBClient.pubkey);
        System.out.println("PUBKEY SERVER: " + HexEncoder.byteArrayToHexString(CBClient.pubkey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("standard length: " + key.getEncoded().length);
        byte[] encryptedAesKey = key.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("wrapped length: " + encryptedAesKey.length);
        //this.output.write(encryptedAesKey);
        this.output.write(encryptedAesKey);
        this.output.flush();

        System.out.println("wrapped key: " + HexEncoder.byteArrayToHexString(encryptedAesKey));

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        this.output = new BufferedOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(this.output, cipher));     
        this.input = new BufferedInputStream(new CipherInputStream(this.input, cipher));

        this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.output));
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.input));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I try to solve this problem for about 2 days now and I'm really exhausted. I guess it's so easy but I just don't see it.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you rolling your own encrypted link instead of using SSL?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick reply, I think using SSL is not that good because the software has to run on my customers' servers and they should not be forced to generate SSL certs.

Comment: cryptography is hard. you shouldn't be rolling your own system. the odds of you developing something that is secure are not good. Secure exchange of crypt keys is not something you can just whip out in a couple hours and assume you're secure. I know enough to know that I'd NEVER attempt doing my own exchange protocol.

Comment: Let me sum it up, you recommend using basic SSL. Let's assume I'll implement everything on top of SSL, do I need to let my customers create SSL certs or can I just do that automatically within my software? It's needed that the customers doesn't really "see" the encryption thingy, it just should work as not encrypted - I don't know if you understand what I'm trying to say...

Comment: only the server would need a cert, really. just like YOU don't need a cert in your browser to be able to access an ssl-enabled site. The only time you'd need client-certs is if you need mutual authentication at the ssl level. having a login system would handle that without ever needing client certs.

Comment: Yeah, I know how SSL works, but my point is that I ship the client as well as the server, because it's some kind of application for administrators to install it in their business network and stuff. I guess I can just call this "keytool" thingy from my program, is that right?

Comment: It's common for admins to have to setup an SSL cert once in a new application. at the least, you can configure it to generate self-signed certs on first run, and if the admin wants, they can buy their own cert and install it overtop of your default one. -- I agree, don't try to roll your own encryption, it's very hard to get right. even the professional cryptography-is-all-they-do-guys get it wrong.

Comment: Well, I will dig into SSL with Java but this keystore thingy and launch parameters doesn't seem very comfortable to use.

Comment: I could take a look at this, but currently you are already making a lot of basic mistakes such as using default mode of encryption (ECB for AES) and not adding a MAC. Then there is the fact that you cannot trust just any RSA public key that you receive. Basically, this protocol is borked, use SSL. Crypto is never easy, and it becomes *less* easy if you stray from the common paths. If you are feeling comfortable, then the attacker probably feels the same :)